# подскажите, можно ли как-то между роутами сохранять параметр match.params?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

подскажите, можно ли как-то между роутами сохранять параметр?
например match.params.id я получаю на главной странице в компоненте Main

(компонент Main под ройтов /:id)

/:id

далее юзер ходит по роутам, но этот параметр должен сохраняться между роутами и доступен на каждом роуте

Можно ли сделать это посредство router react?

Comment: а что должно происходить, если юзер перейдет на какой-нибудь отличающийся от main роут по прямой ссылке, откуда ваше приложение должно брать значение id в таком случае?